# Confused by Dafny postcondition messages

Tags: verification, dafny

A very simple multiplication code:

```
method Product1 (m: nat, n: nat) returns (res:nat) 
ensures res == m * n;      
{  
    var m1: nat := 0; 
    var n1: nat := 0; 
    res := 0; 
    while (m1 < m)    
   { 
    n1 := 0; 
    while (n1 < n)  
    { 
        res := res + 1;
        n1 := n1 + 1; 
    } 
    m1 := m1 + 1; 
    } 
}
```

When I verify it with dafny, it says:

```
     Description                                        Line Column
1   A postcondition might not hold on this return path. 8   4
2   This is the postcondition that might not hold.      2   16
```

I get it says under some conditions, res != m*n, but I can't figure it out.